# Looping on the Registration Ids to be sent to GCM in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I am having an issue here with looping around the Registration Ids from the MYSQL Database in **PHP**.
Here is the way I implemented it but I'm sure that something is going wrong with it.

```
$apiKey = array();
    $i = 0;
    if($_POST['course1'] == '1')
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT Registration_id FROM students WHERE course1 ='1' ")))
        {

            $apiKey[$i] = $row['Registration_id'];
            $i++;

        }

    }
```

**BUT here** it gives me an error in the Android LogCat like that:

```
11-27 16:56:25.336: E/JSON(972): Array<br />n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution
 time of 30 seconds exceeded in
 <b>/home/Php/send.php</b> on line
 <b>34</b><br />n
11-27 16:56:25.346: E/JSON Parser(972): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:
Value Array<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Accept more answers to your previous questions to get one here from me.

Comment: So ? (seems that you are quick at asking for answers but slow to tell if it solved your problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script is taking too much time to complete. That means your loop probably runs forever.

You are querying the database on each loop iteration, the result is $row will always be the first row of your query.

On a side note, you should not be using the `mysql_` functions anymore (they are deprecated, see the PHP documentation).

Try something like:

```
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT Registration_id FROM students WHERE course1 ='1' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query_result ) ) {
  // ...
}
```